# Angularjs - unable to call web api service from another project of same solution - VS2015

Tags: angularjs, web-services, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

It could be a simple scenario for you but not for you, I tried seaching the web for this bu didnt find anything useful.

Today I came across one strange scenario. I have written a web api service which return me a JSON object. I created one more project for AngularJS application under same solution but under different project.
When I was calling the $http service from the angular app to get the data from web api, it was not working. Initially I was using chrome and firefox only.
But when I opened the angular application in IE browser, it worked. Its very strange scenario.

At the same I time I wrote one angular code in web api project and that angular code was able to fetch the data even though I opened the angular application in chrome or firefox.

Can anyone please guide why chrome or firefox are not able to get the details if the project is different.

Angular Code

```
 var app = angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("controller", function ($scope, $http, $log) {
                $http({
                        url: 'http://localhost:37103/api/employee',
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

                    })
                    .then(function success(response) {
                      //  $scope.employees = response.data;
                        $scope.data = response.data;
                    })
                    .then(function error(response) {
                        $scope.error = response;
                    })

            });
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller="controller">
Data:{{data}} 
</br>
Error: {{error}}

 </body>
```

WebApi Method present in separate project under same solution

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using MyWebAPIService.Models;

 namespace MyWebAPIService.Controllers
 {
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Employee
    Employee[] employees = {
        (new Employee { Id=1,Name="A",Gender="Male",Salary=77777}),
        (new Employee { Id=2,Name="B",Gender="Male",Salary=2222}),
        (new Employee { Id=3,Name="C",Gender="Female",Salary=55555}),
        (new Employee { Id=4,Name="D",Gender="Male",Salary=78787}),
        (new Employee { Id=5,Name="F",Gender="Female",Salary=8888}),
        (new Employee { Id=6,Name="G",Gender="Female",Salary=4444}),
        (new Employee { Id=7,Name="H",Gender="Male",Salary=3333}),
        (new Employee { Id=8,Name="I",Gender="Male",Salary=77777}),
        (new Employee { Id=9,Name="J",Gender="Female",Salary=45897})
    };

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        return employees;
    }

    // GET: api/Employee/5
    public Employee Get(int id)
    {
        foreach(Employee e in employees)
        {
            if(e.Id == id)
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
        Employee temp = new Employee();
        temp.Id = -1;
        return temp;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the relevant code bits. It is really difficult to get a sense of what the actual problem is without looking at code.

Comment: @frishi > Code inserted in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the problem was with the asyn call, with the help of below response I was able to solve my problem.

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/40191484/1997983
```