# AngularJS - Unable to call http serrvice using factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

To resolve my issue I have gone through many articles on different sites, but none resolved it.
I'm writing a simple AngularJS application. I'm quite new to Angular. I have written a factory method which call the $http service which gets the data from the web api. Web api is running fine and its returning the JSON object as expected.

Angular Code

```
 var app = angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("controller", function ($scope, WebFactory) {
                $scope.data = "data";
                $scope.error = "error";
                $scope.data=WebFactory.getData();

            })
            .factory("WebFactory", function ($http) {
                var obj = {};

                obj.getData = function()
                {
                    $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:37103/api/employee",                      
                    }).then(function success(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .then(function error(response) {
                        return response;
                    });
                    return 'No data';
                }
                return obj;

            });
```

HTML code

```
 <body ng-controller="controller">

data: {{data}}
<br/>
error: {{error}}
<br />
```

I have spent 2 days, but still dont know why its not working.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, I cant see any errors, it says "HTML1300: Navigation occurred." only.

Comment: Your getData method is not making much sense. $http() returns a promise  that will be resolved when you receive response. Its async call. So, from get data you return "No data" in any case. When response comes, you simply process it in callback, but nothing is using it afterwards.

Comment: On fiddler, its shwoing me the JSON object when I hit the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("controller", function ($scope, WebFactory) {
                $scope.data = "data";
                $scope.error = "error";
                $scope.data = {}
                WebFactory.getData().then(function success(response) {
                        $scope.data = response.data;
                    });
            })
            .factory("WebFactory", function ($http) {
                var obj = {};

                obj.getData = function()
                {
                    return $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:37103/api/employee",                      
                    })
                }
                return obj;
            });
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Vladimir. I got your explanation and its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're missing an [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) declaration

Secondly, you are misusing the then callback. It accepts three parameters: success callback, error callback, finally callback. 
As the first then executes the success, then it executes the second callback that always returns the response, but I assume it is not intended to be that way and you could use the get function which is more easy to use.
It should be:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:37103/api/employee").then(function(response){
     //Do something with successfull response
 },
  function(error){ //do something with the error});
```

See documentation about [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Lastly, you are dealing with promises and async code, yet returning response or string instead of the promise with the result. So the getData() should look like this:

```
obj.getData = function(){
   return    $http.get("http://localhost:37103/api/employee");
}
```

And use the then(success,error,finally) callbacks in the controller or if you want to provide values on the error/finally callbacks in the service, you should use the $q service

```
obj.getData(){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 $http.get(...).then(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
   },
   function(error){
       deferred.reject("No Data");
   });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Of course you would have to provide $q service to the WebFactory

Comment: thanks for your response friend, the issue was with the async call and Vladimir has provided the resolution and its working fine at my end.

Comment: And the HTML which I provided was just part of the page. thanks